# sharepoint administrative server not started causing sharepoint deployment instability

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, errors

When i deploy anything to a variety of sharepoint servers i get problems with some packages failing, from what i can see the only error given is as below.

```
The timer job for this operation has been created, but it will fail because the
administrative service for this server is not enabled. If the timer job is sched
uled to run at a later time, you can run the jobs all at once using stsadm.exe -
o execadmsvcjobs. To avoid this problem in the future, enable the Windows ShareP
oint Services administrative service, or run your operation through the STSADM.e
xe command line utility.
```

Is this a known problem? I googled for the text but got only one other person with the problem who simply worked round it. I'm trying to batch deploy solutions programmatically and so these errors render the whole code worthless if you have to go back and redo bits by hand afterwards.

Is batch deployment simply not possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Batch deployment is possible

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.wsp) do (
    echo File %%f
    "%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN\stsadm.exe" -o addsolution -filename "%%f"
    "%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN\stsadm.exe" -o deploysolution -name "%%f" -allowgacdeployment -immediate -force
)

"%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN\stsadm.exe" -o copyappbincontent
"%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN\stsadm.exe" -o execadmsvcjobs
iisreset.exe
```

As you can see in error message, use stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs. And also check IIS if all application pools and web sites are running.

Comment: i've tried running execadmsvcjobs between each job even just to see if it cures it, im using c# and the object model but the theory is the same surely?

Comment: I've seen the comment ... "Also, in order to stop getting this service related errors, go to the services managment snapin and enable this service: 'Windows SharePoint Services Administration service'"